# Sass: applying a shared class to every selector in a content block

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

If I have a block of styles in Sass like this:

```
.class1 {

   .class2 {

   }

   .class3 {

       .class4 {

       }
   }
}
```

How can I use Sass to transform the above into the form below? I would like to avoid repeatedly typing `.class` or `#{$i}`.

```
.class1.class {

   .class2.class {

   }

   .class3.class {

       .class4.class {

       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Partial answer: check out the `&` selector in Sass.